# jQuery how to add another value in existing class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have the html code snippet here where i have 2 buttons created with bootstrap, i want to add btn-danger if someone clicks on the "no" and btn-success if on the "yes" in the anchor class.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="someLabel">Label</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="0"/>
                    <input id="someID" type="checkbox" name="sumName" value="1" class="hidden"/>
                    <div is="0" class="btn-group" tabindex="0" style="">
                      <a is="0" id="neg" class="btn active btn-danger">No</a>
                      <a is="1" id="pos" class="btn ">Yes</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You want to add the classes to what element?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/  https://api.jquery.com/click/ I think you can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Add and data-attribute the button with the class you want to add on click.

I've changed your `a.btn` to `buttons` as it seems more appropriate for this use case

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('button').removeClass('btn-success btn-danger');
  $(this).addClass($(this).data('addClass'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="someLabel">Label</label><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="0" />
  <input id="someID" type="checkbox" name="sumName" value="1" class="hidden" />
  <div is="0" class="btn-group" tabindex="0" style="">
    <button is="0" id="neg" data-add-class="btn-danger" class="btn btn-primary active">No</button>
    <button is="1" id="pos" data-add-class="btn-success" class="btn btn-primary ">Yes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MilonHossain I've updated my answer to reflect your request in Andre's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#neg').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('btn-danger')) {
      $(this).addClass('btn-danger')
    }
  })
  $('#pos').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('btn-success')) {
      $(this).addClass('btn-success')
    }
  })
})
```

[addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) [on click](https://api.jquery.com/click/), if the behavior is recurrent, improve it to be more generic.

Comment: thanks Andre this works fine only i need a little more help if possible i want only one button to be active at a time, like if i click them both one by one both classes are being added in them & stays like that, sorry i'm kind a newbie to jQuery.

Comment: `$('#neg').removeClass('active').removeClass('btn-danger')` for "Yes", and `$('#pos').removeClass('active').removeClass('btn-success')` for "No"

Comment: They are pretty rough examples. You can enhance it more in a second step.